# One Domain, two MX records for two servers

Tags: exchange-2010

I have two email servers, both running server 2010 exchange. They have a DAG configured. The firewall is a managed router using NAT. My thought is to create a second MX record with the registar of the domain. Currently there is one MX record called mail.domain.com but due to NAT I can only point it at one server. Can I create a second MX record using a different public IP also for mail.domain.com and NAT it to the second server?
Example"
MX record for Public IP 1 is mail.domain.com. NAT directs it to 192.168.1.1 for ports 25,443 ect
MX record for Public IP 2 is mail.domain.com  NAT directs it to 192.168.1.2 for ports 25,443,ect

Comment: So each server also has the Hub Transport role installed? How about the Client Access server role? What's your end goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is exactly how MX records are normally configured.

Using DNS Round Robin will result in asymmetric load balancing, though usually not bad enough to care. It is an officially supported configuration however, so MS Support should recognize this configuration (I work for a MS Partner, MS Tech sucks unless you get to 3rd tier support unfortunately).

MX Records have Priority and Weight. The set of MX records with the lowest priority will be tried first for delivery. So if you want one as a Primary and the other Secondary, use 10 and 20 or similar. The weight is a rough guide as to how many clients will get each server record within a priority group. So if both have the same priority, but different weights they should get proportionally allocated traffic (but it only works that way in theory, practice is slightly different for a variety of reasons).

The other route is to have multiple Front-end servers, these would be completely separate from your Mailbox-role servers (which have the DAG). You configure the Front-ends with a load balanced IP and a single MX record to that. This configuration results in symmetric load balancing and rapid failover, but is more complex to setup (especially with the separate server part).

Also, the *nix world has pretty direct equivalents of all this, at least the concepts carry over.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Believe it or not, I asked Microsoft Professional tech support the same question and they could not supply an answer. Instead they suggested I use load balancing but when I read up on that, seems that it does not work with a DAG.

Comment: Depends on how you want to set it up. Edited answer with more details.